# Switching numbers inside string

Tags: c

I got a string, that inside it has:

`2@0.88315@1@1.5005@true@0.112` and it keep going...

I need to switch every number thats 2 or bigger, to 1,
so I wrote this :

```
for (i = 0 ; i < strlen(data) ; i++)
{
    if (data[i] >= 50 && data[i] <= 57) // If it's a number
    {
        data[i] = '1'; // switch it to one
        while (data[i] >= 48 && data[i] <= 57)
        {
           i++;
        }
     }
 }
```

The problem is, that it makes numbers like 0.051511 as 1.111111 too...
Because it doesnt look at a double as one number, but every number seperatly...
How can I do it ?
Thanks

Comment: There is confusion on what the definition of 'number' is. Can you show what the output SHOULD be? Should 2.5005 be changed to 1.1001 or 1.0000 or 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify the question since it is unclear, you want to have the following input:

```
"2@0.88315@1@1.5005@true@0.112"
```

To be modified to be the following:

```
"1@0.88315@1@1@true@0.112"
```

Your problem is that you need to parse each number into a float value to do any sort of comparison. Either this, or you will need to manually parse it by checking for a '.' character. Doing it manually is rigid, error-prone and unnecessary because the C standard library provides functions which can help you.

Since this is homework, I'll give you some tips on how to approach this problem instead of the actual solution. **What you should do is try to write a solution with these steps and if you get stuck, edit the original question with the code you wrote, where it is failing and why you think it is failing.**

Your first step is to tokenise the input into the following:

```
"2"
"0.88315"
"1"
"1.5005"
"true"
"0.112"
```

This can be done by iterating through the string and either splitting it or using the pointer after which a '@' character occurs. Splitting the string can be done with `strtok`. However, `strtok` will split the string by modifying it which is not necessarily needed in our case. The simpler method is simply to iterate through the string and stop each time after a '@' character is reached. The input would then be tokenised to the following:

```
"2@0.88315@1@1.5005@true@0.112"
"0.88315@1@1.5005@true@0.112"
"1@1.5005@true@0.112"
"1.5005@true@0.112"
"true@0.112"
"0.112"
```

Some of these substrings do not start with a string which represents a float. You will need to determine which of them do. To do this, you can attempt to parse the front of each string as a float. This can be done with `sscanf`. After parsing the floats, you will be able to do the comparison you want to.

You are trying to modify the string into a different length so when replacing a float value by a '1', you need to check the length of the original value. If it is longer than 1 character, you will have to shift the subsequent characters forward. For example:

```
"3.423@1"
```

If you parsed the first token and found it to be `> 2`, you would replace the first character with a '1'. This result in:

```
"1.423@1"
```

You then still need to delete the rest of that token by shifting the rest of the string down to get:

```
"1@1"
```

Comment: You didnt see what I wrote in the main post... i have numbers like 0.28151, and it makes em 1.1111...

Comment: @AmitM9S6: I've added an example. The code I posted works. If you used it and it does something different you've used it wrong. In that case, you should edit your original question with the code you are using. It is not clear from your question exactly what your requirement is. If I have it wrong, you need to give an example input and the output you would expect from it.

Comment: @AmitM9S6: Then give a real example

Comment: If I have the float/int : 2.516181 -> 1.                                  If I have the float 0.185181 -> same number...

Comment: @MikeKwan I don't really know any C, so, why the quotes around the numbers?

Comment: @Keyser: The quotes are because we want to compare against the integer value of the character. That is, according to the ascii table, the integer value of '1' is 49.

Comment: @AmitM9S6: So what should "2@0.88315@1@1.5005@true@0.112" return?

Comment: @MikeKwan Ah, I knew that much :p Smart to get some readability into it. I've already +1'd though.

Comment: @MikeKwan it'd return 1@0.88315@1@1@true@0.112

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're comparing a `char` and an `int` in your if statements.

You should figure out why this matters and compensate for it.

Comment: I know it shouldent be, though the comparing works fine... theres a problem in the algorithm, not the programming...

Comment: It looks like you modified the code to skip characters that were greater than 48 and less than 57. That seems like the opposite of what you want to do. I would modify the while loop condition to `data[i] < '0' || data[i] > '9'`

Comment: I've changed it, but now my problem is that it makes not only int numbers that higher then 2 to 1, but makes float numbers into 1 too(like 0.15165158 into 1.111111111) which I dont want to..

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like you need to first check and see if you're on an ascii number. If so, look ahead to see if you find a decimal. If you find a decimal, ignore that number and move on. If not, you can swap the numbers to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the characters in the string one at a time. If you need to consider everything between the "@" symbols as one number, this won't work. Try to get these numbers into an array, cast them to a double, and then do your comparison against 2.